# User /System Permissions none.(Set to 000)

Tags: macos, permission

A previously called friend of mine (As for now, after this he is no longer called that way) was messing up with my computer without my knowledge , and ultimately he **set the System folder permissions to be 000** for all files in it.

Well, as I realized everything froze and as soon as I restarted the computer it **won't go pass Apple screen**, however I'm able to run gnome on it. Is there any way I could reset the permissions for that entire folder anyhow? Or if there is not, is there any way I could extract some files on the hard drive? I'm completely desperate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boot into single user mode (hold ⌘S on boot), then enter:

```
mount -uw /
chown root /
chmod 1775 /
exit
```

This will reset the permissions for the entire drive and all its contents allowing full read and write, and may take a long time — don't interrupt it. Once you are booted back in, go to Disk Utility and do a permissions repair to set the permissions correctly per OS X.

Comment: Will do! I'll be back to announce how it'd go! Thanks!